# Calculating the Wigner transform of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, fourier-transform, phase-space, wigner-transform

Recently I started to study the formulation of quantum mechanics in the phase space. So I was introduced to the concept of Wigner function and Weyl transform.
I learned that if F is an operator, then I can represent it by an integral as follows:
\begin{equation}
F = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dpdq}{2\pi\hslash}f(p,q)\Delta(p,q)
\end{equation}
Where $f(p,q)$ is the Wigner transform given by:
\begin{equation}
f(p,q) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\frac{i}{\hslash}qu}\langle p+\frac{u}{2}|F|p-\frac{u}{2}\rangle du
\end{equation}
and $\Delta(p,q)$:
\begin{equation}
\Delta(p,q) = \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} e^{\frac{i}{\hslash}pv}|q+\frac{v}{2}\rangle \langle q-\frac{v}{2}|dv
\end{equation}
all of the above expressions were derived using the completeness relations as follows:
\begin{equation}
F = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dp'dp''dq'dq''|q''\rangle\langle q''|p''\rangle \langle p''|F|p'\rangle\langle p'|q'\rangle \langle q'|\end{equation}
and the following variable change was also taken
\begin{equation}
2p =p'+p'',
2q = q'+q'',
u = p''-p',
v = q''-q'
\end{equation}

Could someone show me what these calculations would look like for a numerical example of some observable operator. I tried to calculate for one of the pauli matrices, but I was stuck in the middle of the calculations.
My learning becomes more consistent when I see practical examples, if anyone can help me with this problem, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pauli matrices are mere constant matrices acting on 2d spinors, not functions of *x* or *p*, so you may be barking up the wrong tree.

I assume you or your text have evaluated the free particle hamiltonian,
$$
h(p,q) = \frac{1}{2m}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\frac{i}{\hslash}qu}\langle p+\frac{u}{2}|\hat p^2|p-\frac{u}{2}\rangle du\\
\frac{1}{2m}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\frac{i}{\hslash}qu}(p-u/2)^2\langle p+\frac{u}{2}| p-\frac{u}{2}\rangle du\\ = \frac{1}{2m}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\frac{i}{\hslash}qu}(p-u/2)^2 ~\delta(u) ~ du =\frac{p^2}{2m}~~ .
 $$

The operators need not be observables. Try the hermitean parity operator,
$$
P=\int \!\! dp ~~|-p\rangle\langle p| ~~\leadsto
$$
$$ \Pi (q,p)=
\int\!\!du dp' e^{iqu/\hbar} ~~\langle p+u/2 | -p'\rangle \langle p'|p-u/2\rangle \\ 
=\int\!\!du dp' ~ e^{iqu/\hbar} ~~ \delta( p+u/2 +p')  \delta( p-u/2 -p') \\
=\int\!\!du  ~ e^{iqu/\hbar} ~~ \delta(2 p )  =\frac{h}{2}\delta(q) \delta(p)~.
$$

Comment: Thanks again for helping me with my questions. You,sir,  have always answered my questions about formalism in phase space since my first question on the subject in 2021 here on the forum.
Thank you, you always help me.